# strmqcfg doesn't launch ibm mq websphere

Tags: ibm-mq

I installed 8.0.0.9-WS-MQC-Win64 IBM MQ client into my 64-bit windows machine but I can't launch it by command strmqcfg. I checked my registry and there Local Clients\Windows NT Client in its subkey is installed. According to IBM document that means IBM MQ is installed. Do I need to add user group at this then I can launch IBM MQ client? Plus there are two component available under IBM WebSphere MQ menu in the start menu that is  1. IBM key management (installation 1) 2. Prepare Websphere MQ wizard (installation1). Does anybody have any idea about this? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The MQ Client does not include MQ Explorer that is why you cannot find it.  If you want to install MQ Explorer then you need to download and install [SupportPac MS0T](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021041)